# Improving Query looking at multiple tables for existence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

Given the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConsolidatedRecords]
(
    [SessionKey]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , [EntityID]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].        [EntityList] ( EntityID ) 
  , [EntityName]   NVARCHAR(128)    NOT NULL
  , [SurrogateKey] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
  , [RecordID]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY ( [SessionKey], [EntityName], [RecordID], [SurrogateKey] ) CLUSTERED
);
GO

CREATE #CurrentSession TABLE ([SessionKey] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #CurrentSession VALUES (NEWID());

-- ... long, involved process to populate ConsolidatedRecords
```

I have a query against `ConsolidatedRecords` table that checks for existence of specific entity records which works, but is hard to maintain and frankly is ugly.  I am attempting to fix these issues but am not being vary successful, so I am turning to you:

```
SELECT [SessionKey]   = records.[SessionKey]
     , [SurrogateKey] = records.[SurrogateKey]
  FROM [dbo].[ConsolidatedRecords] records
  JOIN #CurrentSession             session ON records.[SessionKey] = session.[SessionKey]
 WHERE ( EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity1] one   WHERE records.RecordID = one.[Entity1ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity1' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity2] two   WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity2ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity2' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity3] three WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity3ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity3' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity4] four  WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity4ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity4' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity5] five  WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity5ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity5' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity6] six   WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity6ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity6' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity7] seven WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity7ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity7' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity8] eight WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity8ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity8' )
      OR EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Entity9] nine  WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity9ID] AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity9' )
       );
```

One of the issues with this is that in the actual case, there are quite a few more than nine entities in question.

I have tried the following, but the performance is worse - some of these entity tables are quite large - 100,000 records or more.  In all cases I am querying against the primary key.

```
       SELECT [SessionKey]   = records.[SessionKey]
            , [SurrogateKey] = records.[SurrogateKey]     
           FROM [dbo].[ConsolidatedRecords] records
           JOIN #CurrentSession             session ON records.[SessionKey] = session.[SessionKey]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity1]             one     ON records.RecordID     = one.[Entity1ID]      AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity2]             two     ON records.RecordID     = two.[Entity2ID]      AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity2'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity3]             three   ON records.RecordID     = three.[Entity3ID]    AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity3'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity4]             four    ON records.RecordID     = four.[Entity4ID]     AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity4'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity5]             five    ON records.RecordID     = five.[Entity5ID]     AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity5'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity6]             six     ON records.RecordID     = six.[Entity6D]       AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity6'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity7]             seven   ON records.RecordID     = seven.[Entity7ID]    AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity7'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity8]             eight   ON records.RecordID     = eight.[Entity8ID]    AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity8'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Entity9]             nine    ON records.RecordID     = nine.[Entity9ID]     AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity9'
          WHERE one.[Entity1]   IS NOT NULL
             OR two.[Entity2]   IS NOT NULL
             OR three.[Entity2] IS NOT NULL
             OR four.[Entity2]  IS NOT NULL
             OR five.[Entity2]  IS NOT NULL
             OR six.[Entity2]   IS NOT NULL
             OR seven.[Entity2] IS NOT NULL
             OR eight.[Entity2] IS NOT NULL
             OR nine.[Entity2]  IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The uniqueidentifier as a clustered key is not going to help your performance either. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Comment: This screams of a bad data design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT [SessionKey]   = records.[SessionKey]
     , [SurrogateKey] = records.[SurrogateKey]
  FROM [dbo].[ConsolidatedRecords] records
  JOIN #CurrentSession             session 
   ON records.[SessionKey] = session.[SessionKey]
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM [dbo].[Entity1] one   
             WHERE records.RecordID = one.[Entity1ID] 
               AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity1' 
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 
             FROM [dbo].[Entity2] two   
             WHERE records.RecordID = two.[Entity2ID] 
               AND records.[EntityName] = N'Entity2'
             UNION ALL 
              ...
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL and create a view of all the entity tables. You can use the view in the query. I am not sure if it will help the performance but it becomes more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without knowing the table definitions. **IF** Entity1 through Entity9 have common attributes (aka columns), then combine them into a single table with an extra column named "EntityName" like ConsolidatedRecords. Then join on EntityName and cut the query down to 2 tables.  If Entity1 through 9 are truly unique, then you could union all the separate sub-queries!

HTH,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

If this is a batching type operation (you don't execute it often), I would suggest creating a temporal (or physical) table with the results of all `RecordID` that have a record on any of those entity tables. This table with a `CLUSTERED INDEX` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) will execute a lot faster than your original query.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ValidRecords') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ValidRecords

CREATE TABLE #ValidRecords (
    RecordID INT,
    EntityType VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (RecordID, EntityType))

INSERT INTO #ValidRecords (RecordID, EntityType)
SELECT [Entity1ID] AS RecordID, 'Entity1' AS EntityType FROM [dbo].[Entity1] UNION ALL
SELECT [Entity2ID] AS RecordID, 'Entity2' AS EntityType FROM [dbo].[Entity2] UNION ALL
SELECT [Entity3ID] AS RecordID, 'Entity3' AS EntityType FROM [dbo].[Entity3] UNION ALL
SELECT [Entity4ID] AS RecordID, 'Entity4' AS EntityType FROM [dbo].[Entity4]
-- ......

SELECT 
    [SessionKey] = records.[SessionKey],
    [SurrogateKey] = records.[SurrogateKey]
FROM 
    [dbo].[ConsolidatedRecords] records
    INNER JOIN #CurrentSession session ON records.[SessionKey] = session.[SessionKey]
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 'valid record' FROM #ValidRecords AS V WHERE records.RecordID = V.RecordID AND records.[EntityName] = V.EntityType)
```

On the other hand, if creating that table takes a time you can't afford, you can try switching your several `EXISTS` into one `EXISTS` with several `UNION ALL`, although performace might not improve, depending on how complex the full query is.